# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^ki^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom {k+1}{i} =(k+1)^k$

Tags: number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^ki^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom {k+1}{i} =(k+1)^k$

where k is a positive integer.

Any hints can help.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion principle can be used for counting the number of functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ to $\{1,2,\ldots,k+1\}$. How many functions $f$ do you have such that there are exactly $i$ elements in the range of $f$?

Comment: This one is trivial. A bit of calculus goes a long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We can write OPs claim by putting the RHS to the left as:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}(-1)^{k-i}i^k=0\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}

We use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of a series.

> We observe
>   \begin{align*}
>   [x^k](e^x-1)^{k+1}&=[x^k]\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{k+1}\\
>   &=0\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
>
> On the other hand we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   [x^k](e^x-1)^{k+1}&=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}(-1)^{k+1-j}e^{jx}\\
>   &=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}(-1)^{k+1-j}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}j^r\frac{x^r}{r!}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}(-1)^{k+1-j}j^k\tag{3}\\
>   \end{align*}

Combining (2) and (3) and multiplying with $-\frac{1}{k!}$ we get
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{j}(-1)^{k-j}j^k=0
  \end{align*}

and the claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^n (-1)^{n-k} {n+1\choose k} =
(n+1)^n.$$

Re-write this as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} k^n (-1)^{n-k} {n+1\choose k} = 0.$$

Introduce
$$k^n = 
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp(kz) \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{n-k} {n+1\choose k}
\exp(kz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (\exp(z)-1)^{n+1} \; dz.$$

This is
$$[z^n] (\exp(z)-1)^{n+1} = 0$$

because $$\exp(z)-1 = z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{6} +\cdots$$

This is essentially the same as the answer by @MarkusScheuer which I upvoted.